# Is there a chinese term similar to semifera?

Tags: translation, meaning-in-context

I am looking for a chinese term, that has the same meaning as the Greek diphues (διφυής) “of two natures”, or latin semifera, which means part human, part animal. It is a term to encompase mythological creatures like centaurs, the Minotaur, sphinx, etc... The closest I have come is Bànrén bànshòu (半人半兽) "half man, half animal" or Banren Banwu (半人半物) "half man, half thing". I am looking for something more elegant or shorter term, if there is one.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your assumptions are correct.

> διφυῆ, - having two natures. The epithet is διφυής (adj. fem./masc.
> nom.). There are various interpretations of this epithet but perhaps
> it refers to Diónysos expressing both the death of the mortal nature
> and the resurrection of the soul as a God. It could also refer to him,
> as is said of his father in the Orphic Rhapsodic hymn to Zefs in the
> theogony, that he is **both male and female**.

两性人
hermaphrodite: 雌雄同体人

Latin: ferus "wild"
semiferal: half wild

Κέκροψ, Kékrops was a mythical king of Attica which derived from him its name Cecropia

> "described as having his top half shaped like a man and the bottom
> half in serpent or fish-tail form"

mermaid: 美人鱼

Otherwise, 半兽人 will do.

Comment: The term διφυής  is applied to Kékrops, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cecrops_I

Comment: That sob has a lot to answer for: apparently, he introduced reading, writing AND, wait for it, MARRIAGE!!

Answer (score 1):

“半人半兽” is the best for the class, I think. Though a mermaid is a “semifera” but not a “兽”.

And for a specified creature, it may have a specified name, 半人马, 兽人, 美人鱼, etc.

“人面獸身” and “獸面人身” are not pretty good, because, for example, a centaur is typically have a human body and a horse body. And 半兽人 may be treated as a specified creature just like 兽人.

Comment: From what little I can find, Bàn shòurén (半兽人) is treated as the word Orcs

Answer (score 0):

人面獸身 or 獸面人身.

There were two famous 獸面人身 characters - 孫悟空 and 豬八戒 in ancient Chinese folk-story "西遊記" :)